# quote inside quote for then i should see cucumber prolmem rails

Tags: cucumber, quote

I can clearly see the text in browser.

```
characters should be "R", "P", or "B".
```

But when I write a step a cucumber step

```
Then I should see "characters should be \"R\", \"P\", or \"B\"."
```

It says its

```
Undefined step: "I should see "characters should be \"R\", \"P\", or \"B\"."" (Cucumber::Undefined)
```

and says to define the step as

```
Then /^I should see "([^"]*)"R\\"([^"]*)"P\\"([^"]*)"B\\"([^"]*)"$/ do |arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4|
    pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```

Why is cucumber not recognizing this step?

Or is it the escaping problem of the quote inside quote?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A Pystring might work. Use three doublequotes to indicate an entire line as a string.

Cucumber step

```
Then I should see
"""
characters should be "R", "P", or "B".
"""
```

Step definition

```
Then /^I should see "([^"]*)"$/ do |string|
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end
```